# Firebase Fcm token of user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ok I am trying my best to figure out how to implement notifications between separate users in firebase, and I have come to a block in the road, and I do not know if I have figured it out correctly. Basically I know you need to know the device token you want to send a message to, and the server key. So I am asking this, I grab the device token with this function after registering for the firebase token refresh notification,

```
 func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
  print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
}
}
```

But wait my question is do I store this token in firebase database under users like an example of this:

[image]

And then when a user wants to send a new message, send it the token and the server key?

[image]

Basically I would like to know how I should get/store the fcmToken of a user I want to send to. Please help, thank you.

Comment: did you get a solution to your question?

Comment: I basically just used oneSignal, this solved my problem